# Найти верный алгоритм поиска контрольной суммы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, ассемблер, hex

Есть пакети данных, например:

```
8D 2D 0D 00 00 BC 00 97 
BD 2E 0D 00 00 BC 00 A4 
48 2F 0D 00 00 BC 00 50 
47 20 0E 00 00 BC 00 53 
4D 21 0D 00 00 BC 00 5B
```

У каждому пакете есть по 8 байт, где 1 и 8 байти - контрольная сумма, 
а 2-7 -> байти полученной информации, нужно найти алгоритм, в котором делаем какие-то операции вычисления над байтами порядка 2-7 и получим новое значение, к примеру X. 
После этого ми делаем какую-то операцию между X и 1 байтом (например XOR) и получаем значение 8 байта, так-же и наоборот, делаем эту же операцию между 8 байтом и получаем значение первого.

Я начал складать алгоритм и вот что у меня получилось:
1) 87 2C 0E 00 00 BC 00 9F

```
2C + 0E + BC = F6
F6/A = 18  (почему А, наибольше подошло, делил на 10 (16) логика ломалась)
18 XOR 87 = 9F (восьмой байт)
18 XOR 9F = 87 (первый байт)
```

здесь сошлось

2) 8D 2D 0D 00 00 BC 00 97

```
2D + 0D+ BC = F6
F6/A = 18
18 XOR 8D = 95 (+2 , должно получиться 97)
18 XOR 97 = 8F (-2, 8D)
```

Здесь похибка или сообщения пришло з ошибкой, или мой алгоритм не верный

3) 48 2F 0D 00 00 BC 00 50

```
2F + 0D + BC = F8
F8/A = 18
18 XOR 48 = 50
18 XOR 50 = 48
```

(здесь тоже хорошо)

4)BD 2E 0D 00 00 BC 00 A4

```
2E + 0D + DC = F7
F7/A = 18
18 XOR BD = A5 (-1 , A4)
A4 XOR 18 = BC (+1, BD должно быть)
```

5) 82 22 0E 00 00 BC 00 94

```
22 + 0E + BC = EC
EC/A = 17
17 XOR 82 = 95 (-1, 94)
17 XOR 94 = 83 (-1, 82)
```

Есть еще много примеров, например

```
1B 2C 96 26 00 73 2C 5F
66 2D 96 26 00 6B 2D 38
```

И тд...

Буду благодарен за любую помощь у вычислениях, я на 90% уверен что делаю что-то не так

Comment: Ваше заявление, что "первый и последний байты - это контрольная сумма" достоверно на 100%? Для анализа нужно больше правильных пакетов (без ошибок).

Comment: Здравствуйте, обновив вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792950/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B